# how to find text of anchor tag on edit button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
   <div class="testcaselist_row"><ul><li id="tc_1" class="clickTestCaseRow"><a href="#" style="color: #ffffff!important;">q</a><a class="delete deleteTestCase_h"></a><button class="edit_h" href="#">Edit</button></li></ul></div>
```

can you please tell me how to find text of anchor tag on edit button click ?

```
$(document).on('click','.edit_h',function(e){
    alert('rdit'+$(this).closest('li').attr('id'));//getting iD
    alert($(this).closest('a').text()); //getting undefined  it shouted be "q"
    $("#editTestCaseId").popup("open");


e.stopPropagation();
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The anchor tag that you are trying to find is not a parent. so you cannot use `.closest()`

Try,

```
alert($(this).closest('li').find('a:first').text());
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u6W3C/)

Answer (score 0):

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lj6he/4/)

try this

```
$(document).on('click','.edit_h', function(){

    alert( $(this).closest("li").find("a:eq(0)").text());


});
```